# Is there jQuery like selectors for Java XML parsing?

Tags: java, jquery, xml, parsing

When I want to find elements from XML in with jQuery, i can just use CSS selectors. Is there any similar selector system for XML parsing in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query syntax for XML is called XPath.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently creating a sort of "jQuery port to Java". It is called jOOX and will provide most of jQuery's DOM navigation and manipulation methods. In addition to a simple selector expression language, standard XPath and XML transformation is supported, based on the standard Java DOM API

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX

Some sample code:

```
// Find the order at index for and add an element "paid"
$(document).find("orders").children().eq(4)
           .append("<paid>true</paid>");

// Find those orders that are paid and flag them as "settled"
$(document).find("orders").children().find("paid")
           .after("<settled>true</settled>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [E4X](http://www.w3schools.com/e4x/default.asp) or [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) to query your XML file. I would recommend using the new E4X technology as it's more easy to use than XPath.

jQuery only offers standard hierarchical functions to parse XML files ([see here](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/)) as it's not his purpose to do otherwise.